# Receiving Audio Session Callbacks for State Changes with NAudio

Tags: audio, naudio

I'd like to receive callbacks when audio sessions start and end with NAudio. The following code is working:

```
    private void SetupMediaSessionCallbacks()
    {
        // Foreach output endpoint
        foreach (var md in new MMDeviceEnumerator().EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active))
        {
            md.AudioSessionManager.OnSessionCreated += OnSessionCreated;
        }
    }
```

This code triggers when new audio sessions are created. I'm new to NAudio, so I don't understand how to setup RegisterEventClient to receive state change events:

```
    private void OnSessionCreated(object sender, IAudioSessionControl newSession)
    {
        // Not working, need help here!
        AudioSessionControl audioSession = new AudioSessionControl(newSession);
        IAudioSessionEventsHandler handler = null;
        AudioSessionEventsCallback notifications = new AudioSessionEventsCallback(test);
        handler.OnStateChanged += new EventHandler<AudioSessionState>(notifications_StateChanged);
        audioSession.RegisterEventClient(handler);
    }
```

Here's the callback, which I believe is correct:

```
    void notifications_StateChanged(object sender, AudioSessionState newState)
    {
        if (newState == AudioSessionState.AudioSessionStateActive)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("StateChanged");
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've searched high and low for documentation for this.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I need to create my own class that inherits from IAudioSessionEventsHandler. Here's the code for OnSessionCreated:

```
private void OnSessionCreated(object sender, IAudioSessionControl newSession)
{
    AudioSessionControl audioSession = new AudioSessionControl(newSession);
    NAudioEventCallbacks callbacks = new NAudioEventCallbacks();
    AudioSessionEventsCallback notifications = new AudioSessionEventsCallback(callbacks);
    audioSession.RegisterEventClient(callbacks);

}

public class NAudioEventCallbacks : IAudioSessionEventsHandler
{
    public void OnChannelVolumeChanged(uint channelCount, IntPtr newVolumes, uint channelIndex) { }

    public void OnDisplayNameChanged(string displayName) { }

    public void OnGroupingParamChanged(ref Guid groupingId) { }

    public void OnIconPathChanged(string iconPath) { }

    public void OnSessionDisconnected(AudioSessionDisconnectReason disconnectReason) { }

    public void OnStateChanged(AudioSessionState state) { }

    public void OnVolumeChanged(float volume, bool isMuted) { }
}
```

I can now set breakpoints in NAudioEventCallbacks that work as expected.